# Creating data-attributes on table rows with jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to read up on the jQuery plugin [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) but I'm running short when skimming through the documentation and demos.

What I want to accomplish is to use some parts of my JSON data to display in columns, and other parts to create HTML5 data-attributes on each table row. However, I'm unable to figure out if jqGrid can handle this, and if so, how.

**An example of what I want to do:**

From the following data (whitespace added for readability)

```
[
 {
     'id': 1, 
     'type': 0, 
     'name': 'first', 
     'address': '1524, 3rd street', 
     'X': 18.0068922, 
     'Y': 59.31076795
 },
 {
     'id': 7819, 
     'type': 0, 
     'name': 'not first', 
     'address': 'South Corner', 
     'X': 144.18457031, 
     'Y': -22.20774917
 }
]
```

I want to create the following table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-id="1" data-type="0" 
            data-x-coord="18.0068922" data-y-coord="59.3107695">
            <td>first</td>
            <td>1524, 3rd street</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-id="7819" data-type="0"
            data-x-coord="144.18457031" data-y-coord="-22.20774917">
            <td>not first</td>
            <td>South Corner</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, the data attributes may or may not be named the same thing as the properties in the row. Also, not shown in this example, some properties will be used both for showing in the table and for data-attributes.

The API that provides the JSON data is used elsewhere, so I can't change that. The requirements on the data attributes are also defined by another (self-authored) jQuery plugin used elsewhere, so they cannot be changed either.

Is there any way to accomplish this with jqGrid? If so, how? If not, what options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [afterInsertRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) event to get hold of each row inserted into the grid and then modify them as you wish(Add custom attributes using [jQuery.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)).

Comment: @TomasLycken: The usage of `afterInsertRow` make processing of the data response slowly because `gridview: true` parameter can't be used. It's better to use `loadComplete` which has the original JSON data as parameter. You can use `jQuerx.data` to place any data in the `<td>` elements. By the way you don't need to set `data-id`. Instead of that you can use `id` attribute `<td>`. The problem is just in which format you return the data from the server and which [jsonReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data) you use.

Comment: @Oleg: `afterInsertRow` along with `addRowData` works fine for me - I've tried it with some real data from the server and it's more than fast enough. It also lets me avoid writing a new `jsonReader` for this quite complicated mapping, which is good since this is the first time ever I use jqGrid :P So all in all this solution is, however suboptimal, good enough for me.

Comment: @TomasLycken: I don't wrote that `afterInsertRow` not works. It is just slow or very slow if the number of rows is large. The difference is easy to explain. If you use `gridview: true` the whole grid body will be constructed *as one HTML string fragment* and then placed as one operation on the page. If you use `afterInsertRow` then every row of data will be placed separately. If you place an element on the page the *web browser have to update position of all existing elements on the page*. It's the reason why one should better not use `afterInsertRow`.

Comment: @Oleg: I understand what you're saying, but what I'm saying is that this works fine for me. Apparently my data sets aren't very large (which doesn't surprise me - the largest ones will be 20 or 30 rows...).